# Getting a NoSuchElementException when trying to find a text box inside a Modal Dialog box while using Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, textbox, modal-dialog

I'm trying to input text into a textbox that's part of a popup dialog page, which I think is a modal dialogue box.

After I successfully click on a button on the page with this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="get_content"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/h3').click()
```

I get a dialog box with some textboxes. When I try to input text into one of the textboxes with the following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="textbox"]').send_keys("Update Cases")
```

I get the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="textbox"]"}
```

I tried clicking on the popup dialog box:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="popup_dialog"]').click()
```

Only to get this error:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable: element has zero size
```

I tried putting this line before the code above to switch to the active screen:

driver.switch_to.active_element

The line didn't generate any errors. But `"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="textbox"]"` still yielded `NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="textbox"]"`}.

I tried:
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="textbox"]'))).send_keys('Update Cases')
I got a `TimeoutException`.

The following is the outer HTML for the popup dialog box.

The page is internal, but the following is partial outer HTML code for the

```
<div id="popup_dialog"><div class="popup_dialog create_request_dialog"><div class="item_header has_icon"><div class="item_icon"><img src="/servicedesk/customershim/secure/viewavatar?...<div class="popup_dialog_cover"></div></div>
```

Thus far, none of the above has worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I see no elements with `id="textbox"` in HTML you presenting here.
As about the

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="popup_dialog"]').click()
```

Try adding a wait condition there, something like

```py
 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="popup_dialog"]'))).click()
```

We can only guess about the correct solution here since we can't see and debug the page you are working on